# Rating Corporate Content

Tags: ratings, intranet

Does anyone have experience with using user ratings in an intranet context? Using systems like SE or Reddit do that encourage users to post high quality content and identify content that is not useful? I am working on our Intranet design, but would like to know what pitfalls may exist; does it tend to offend managers? Do people see the value in it?

Comment: Downvoting coworker's content seems like asking for drama. Even Upvoting I can see issues with. Never implemented it myself though

Comment: @BenBrocka, I think I agree with you, but are you suggesting that the anonymity of the Internet is what makes a site like SE or Reddit work?

Comment: Votes, just like here, would be anonymous. I certainly am concerned about potential drama, but reality often confounds expectations; that is why I'm hoping someone has seen this in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At work we have two systems on this topic, which differs from the gamification implementation of SE sites. On our intranet we have a star-system on our knowledge bank. Employees are engouraged to star knowledge elements if thoy found them useful or not. This is an exact copy of App Store, Google Play (formerly known as Android Market) and Windows Phone Marketplace. No gamification element there.

But to get people to share their knowledge, we have an insentive for best content upload a month. It could be cinema tickets, football tickets, concert tickets or any other gift card. It's not in the amount that you would spend all your time uploading great content, but more of a token of appreciation to the employee.

Comment: What I do for a living? I'm a SharePoint consultant delivering intranet solutions to our customers :-)

Answer (score 0):

An great idea that might be worth exploring is to chose a path that will use emotion more than rating.

A similar solution is currently being used on this Italian on-line news-paper (see bottom of the article to see the rating scale or top of the article for a overview of the rating given by the user):

Visit: http://www.corriere.it/scienze/13_agosto_05/hamburger-carne-sintetica-staminali_cc274bb0-fdb0-11e2-a2a4-b405456a2122.shtml

You could see the similar system keeping the anonymous comment idea and changing the adjective for each "face" to something more relevant to usefulness of the content accessed.